# Get a reference to an element in React for using 'fromEvent' method of rxjs

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

In a React [project](https://github.com/Fidelya1988/Timer-rxjs/blob/main/src/App.js) that uses `rxjs`, I need to get a reference to an HTML element. I am using `React.createRef`:

```js
const buttonWait = React.createRef();
```

```
<button ref={buttonWait}> Wait </button>
```

But `{ current: null }` is printed to the console. How to get a link to an element to add to `fromEvent` and subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

According to [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) on refs, `React.createRef()` is not to be used in functional components:

> **You may not use the ref attribute on function components** because they don’t have instances.

Consider [using `useRef()` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components):

```js
import { useRef } from "react";
```

```js
const buttonWait = useRef(null);
```

```js
<button ref={buttonWait}> Wait </button>
```